# Some questions in regards to declaring Models in Kohana ORM

Tags: kohana, kohana-orm

So I just started learning to use ORM, went with Jelly when I first started learning Ko3, and have run into a few questions... they may seem stupid so please bear with me.

First I noticed that declaring the Model is enough to start using it, without having to break down the fields. Is this some automagic I'm unaware of? If so... does it cause performance issues and should it be avoided?

I've also noticed two different ways of declaring rules... what's the difference between these two methods?

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        'categoryname' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
        ),
    );
}

protected $_rules = array(
    'categoryname' => array(
        'not_empty' => true,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, ORM will automatically call `SHOW COLUMNS` on empty model. But you can simply [cache it](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/19555/#Comment_19555).
2. `rules()` was added in Kohana 3.1 (3.0 uses `$_rules` property). Now you can apply some logic before return rule list. And its better for model extending, for example:

> ```
> public function rules()
> {
>     return parent::rules() + array('foo' => 'bar');
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for a very clear and helpful answer... and the link... Was just wondering if by chance you knew the answer to the last question on that form by any chance.... "Will 3.0 cache this metadata cross-request, too?" It just sparked my curiosity is all... :)

Comment: AFAIR, `Database` module caches queries for current request only. You must cache them manually (with `Kohana::cache()` call or special `Cache` module). Or define model field in `$table_columns` property, its the best way i think.